# Charles Map Local not working for JSON data?

Tags: ios, json, mocking, charles-proxy

I am trying to simulate (mocking it) a server using Charles. I found out that Charles has something called "Map Local..." which allows me to reply to a client using files I have stored locally.

The files I am pointing to have been stored by right clicking in the Charles Sequence list and choosing "Save Response...".

However when testing this with my iOS app I get the following error message:

```
Failed to get areas: Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
    "text/json",
    "application/json",
    "text/javascript"
)}, got text/plain"
```

So somehow I am not sending the response with the correct header information for Content type. Is there a way of telling Charles that the response is JSON? A possible problem is that the files stored only contains the JSON data and not any header.

Comment: Know nothing of the tool, but make sure your file has a .json suffix.  If that doesn't do it you need to figure out how to set the mime type.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to add a rewrite rule in Charles to change the Content-Type header back to application/json.

Map Local will only give a text/plain Content-Type.

To do this, go to Tools > Rewrite... > Add.

Add all the locations that you are mapping locally and then for the rules, add one that looks like the following:

[image: rewrite rule]

I would never recommend adjusting your code just for Charles as this defeats the point of testing your web services if you can't replicate them exactly.

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm. I had no idea Charles was this powerful. This rewrite function gives so many possibilities.

Comment: @AdamSmith Yep! Its not very well documented but once you get your head around all the features it is awesome!

Comment: I just mapped a local file that is named "localFile.json" and got `"Content-Type" = "application/json"` in the response in my test... I got here looking for a way to modify the headers of the response though, no luck yet.

Comment: Charles will add header values appropriate to the file type you are using for map local. If you want `application/json` for `Content-Type` then make sure the mapped file is of type `.json`. This will prevent you from having to create an additional rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

I know you are asking how to tell Charles to treat response as JSON but on the other hand there is also another solution.

I can see you are using AFNetworking. Your request is expecting to receive `"text/json",
    "application/json",
    "text/javascript"` but your files are `text/plain` so we need to change this.
 While building `AFHTTPRequestOperation` you can set `acceptableContentTypes` with this line of code 
`operation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"];`

So whole code can look like this

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation = [manager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:req success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

   //success

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

  //failure
 }];

operation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"];
[operation start];
```